# How to get the Nambu-Goto action from the Polyakov action by lagrangian multiplier?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action

I consulted some textbooks about string theory, but they only told me that the Nambu-Goto action and the Polyakov action is equivalent. So I searched relevant questions here and got some ways of derivation however I want to know relation between the two actions and lagrangian multiplier.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17349/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Did you mean to ask for the opposite derivation? To reopen this post (v2), consider to align title and main body.