Howe-Tucker to Nambu-Goto Action
Aim to find from the Howe-Tucker action:
$$S_{\text{HT}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^d\sigma\sqrt{-\gamma}(\gamma^{ab}\partial_a X^{\mu}\partial_b X^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}-m^2(d-2))$$
(which is a Polyakov-like action),
the Nambu-Goto form of the action:
$$S_{\text{NG}}=-m^{d-2}\int d^d\sigma\sqrt{-det(\partial_a X^{\mu}\partial_b X^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu})}.$$
I figured for the induced relations that:
$$\gamma^{ab}\delta\gamma_{ab}=2\gamma^{ab}\partial_a X^{\mu}\partial_b\delta X^{\nu}$$
$$\delta\sqrt{-\gamma}=\gamma^{ab}\delta\gamma_{ab}.$$
I have tried to find the equation of motion so that I may substitute it back in. However, I get:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{ab}\partial_a X^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{4}m^2(d-2)=0$$
when I should have
$$-\frac{1}{2}\partial_a X^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{4}\gamma_{ab}(\gamma^{cd}\partial_c X^{\mu}\partial_dX^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}-m^2(d-2)).$$
Any suggestions on where I may be going wrong would be appreciated.

For one thing, your equation of motion doesn't make sense since $\mu,\nu$ are free indices on the first term, but the second term is a scalar. You should probably double check all your algebra carefully. Also in the "correct" equation of motion you reuse $a,b$ as free indices and as dummy indices -- it will help you a lot to choose letters for the indices carefully so it is clear which pairs of indices are contracted and which are free.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17349/2451 and links therein.

@Andrew, yes I missed out the eta term in the first term, I've changed that now as well as the indices in the "correct" EoM. Thank you.
